# How can I run psql from another docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 containers. One of then is for postgresql. Another for php.

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  backend-network:
    driver: bridge
  frontend-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  php-fpm:
    container_name: k4fntr_php-fpm
    build: ./docker/php-fpm
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/k4fntr
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - backend-network
      - frontend-network

  database:
    container_name: k4fntr_database
    build: ./docker/postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      ENV: ${APP_ENV}
      TESTING_DB: ${DB_DATABASE_TESTING}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/postgres/pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
    networks:
      - backend-network
```

I also have sh script which is copy production database into my local.

```
#!/bin/bash
 ssh -p 22000 -C -l user host 'sh /project/copy_prod.sh' > /tmp/backup.sql

 (
  echo "DROP DATABASE prod_copy;"
  echo "CREATE DATABASE prod_copy OWNER k4fntr;"
 ) | (export PGPASSWORD=secret && psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U local)

 export PGPASSWORD=secret && psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U local prod_copy < /tmp/backup.sql
```

but got an error

> bash: psql: command not found

Is it possible to run psql from database container?

Comment: I'd install the PostgreSQL client the same place you're running this script.  Make sure you specify the alternate published port `-p 15432`.  You might be able to point the `-h` option at the host that's running this Docker Compose stack to minimize the number of ssh's required.

Comment: can you add the docker file for your php app ?